# How to declare a variable INTERVAL in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, plpgsql, intervals

I want to write a code that interates from TIMESTAMP_START to TIMESTAMP_END with an variable INTERVAL.
My hardcoded working code looks like this:

```
LOOP 
    ...DO SMTH...

    TIMESTAMP_START := (TIMESTAMP_START + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE);
    EXIT WHEN TIMESTAMP_START > TIMESTAMP_END;
END LOOP;
```

When I try to replace the type of the interval I get a Syntax Error:

```
DECLARE INCREMENT_TYPE  INTERVAL := minute;
...
TIMESTAMP_START := (TIMESTAMP_START + INTERVAL '30' INCREMENT_TYPE);
```

The same happens whe I try to variable the step:

```
DECLARE STEP    text    := '30'; 
...
TIMESTAMP_START := (TIMESTAMP_START + INTERVAL STEP MINUTE);
```

I assuming I am doing something wrong, but googling the documentations does not gave me the answer. What is the correct procedure to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable can only hold a complete value of the underlying data type. You couldn't store just `2018` in a timestamp variable either.

Depending on how you want to use it, and how flexible it should be I see following possibilities:

```
declare 
   increment_value  interval := interval '30' minute;

begin
...
   timestamp_start := (timestamp_start + increment_value);
...
```

That would be helpful if you want to define the increment value only once.

---

If you want to use different interval lengths throughout the function, you could define an interval of a standard length and then multiply that:

```
declare 
   one_minute_interval interval := interval '1' minute;
   one_hour_interval interval := interval '1' hour;

begin
...
   timestamp_start := (timestamp_start + 30 * one_minute_interval);
...
   timestamp_start := (timestamp_start + 5 * one_hour_interval);
```

---

Or a solution that is closer to what you are trying to do:

```
declare 
   increment_type  text := 'minute';

begin
...
   timestamp_start := (timestamp_start + ('30 '||increment_type)::interval);
...
```